# Label pgfplot axes (TikZ)

Tags: tikz-pgf

Second question! I am trying to plot the acoustic and optical phonon branches, and being nowhere near as fluent in Tikz (and Latex for that matter) I only have this crude effort thus far: the relative position of the two branches in the frequency axis is hilariously wrong - but I only need a diagram. 
Now, the question: how do I label the x axis as in the pic shown below? In fact, how do I insert a label? Ideally, I will have labels which I can define myself. 
Thanks :)
[image: Optical/accoustic phonon branches]

```
    \documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \begin{document}
    \centering
      \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
         \begin{axis}[samples=950,xmin=-90,xmax=90,ymin=-.1, ymax=1.8,axis x line=center, axis y line=none, ultra thick,xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty]
         \addplot+[domain=-90:90,mark=none, color = red, ultra thick] {abs{sin( x )}};
         \addplot+[domain=-90:90,mark=none, color = green, ultra thick] {1.2+0.5*sqrt{cos(x)*cos(x)}};
         \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

And here is the result.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

[image: is this what you want?]

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
    \begin{axis}[samples=950, 
        xmin=-90,xmax=90,
        ymin=-.1, ymax=1.8,
        axis x line=center, 
        axis y line=none, 
        ultra thick,
        xlabel = {$q$}, 
        xtick = {-90,0,90},
        xticklabels = {$-\pi/2a$, $0$, $\pi/2a$},
        ytick=\empty]
        \addplot+[domain=-90:90,mark=none, color = red, ultra thick] {abs{sin( x )}};
        \addplot+[domain=-90:90,mark=none, color = green, ultra thick] {1.2+0.5*sqrt{cos(x)*cos(x)}};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

See section 4.15 "Tick options" of the `pgfplots` manual (Version 1.13, at page 311).